# text box value to a javascript variable instantly after change

Tags: text, get, var

i want to type a numerical value in a text box and after i type it i want it to be assigned to a JavaScript variable instantly without submitting it

so the idea is 
type a number
var x = that number instantly

Here is the html

```
<form id="tools">
    <input type="text" id"stk"/>
</form>
```

now what is the javascript? :D

Answer (score 0):

you can achive that assigning an a handler for the event (onKeyUp)... and that handler should assign the  value to the variable. I suggest you to use jQuery instead of pure javascript.

With jQuery should look like this:

```
var x = 0;    
$('#textbox-name').onkeypress(function({
       x = $(this).attr('value');
}));
```

Sorry if I made a mistake with the syntax, but that's the main idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your Jsp :

```
<form action="someAction" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />

    <input type="text" name="value" id="value" />
</form>
```

Java Script needed is :

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){getValue()},5000);

function getValue()
{
    document.getElementById("value").value=document.getElementById("text").value;
}
```

By this type of `JavaScript function` the value of the `text field` will be received by `JavaScript` for every 5 Seconds . If you need instantly you can replace `5000` with `0`. I think its little bit clumsy try to understand it

Comment: I think this answer meets your requirement . If not you can specify your requirement